# What is the Schengen visa type for Academic staff training/Teaching?

Tags: visas, schengen

I am travelling to Spain for university training/teaching purpose for 5 days and I need to know what is the visa type I should choose from the following options:
Business, Sports, Cultural, Other, Study, Visiting family or friends, Medical reasons, Official visit, Transit, Airport transit, Tourism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that "business" is the most appropriate, but I suggest you ask the host university: they are used to dealing with visa issues and they should be able to answer with certainty.